# Need to see if a file exists when virtual directory is called

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am needing to check for a file when the virtual directory is called and rewrite based on whether the page exist or not

Example:

```
/test/page-one - The page /page-one.php exist, so it would call page-one.php?test=1
/test/test-one - The page /test-one.php does not exist, so it would call index.php?test=1&page=test-one
```

Current .htaccess which all works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/$3.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/$2.php?sub_page=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?sub_page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So, I need to check if /test/ is the first directory and do what the current .htaccess does, but add ?test=1 to the rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## one level virtual directory with /test/    
RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ index.php?$1=1 [L,NC,QSA]

## two level virtual directory with /test/    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?$1=1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$2.php?$1=1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?$1=1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## three level virtual directory with /test/    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?sub_page=$3&$1=1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$2.php?sub_page=$3&$1=1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(test)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?$1=1&page=$2&sub_page=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

## one level virtual directory without /test/    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

## two level virtual directory without /test/    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$1.php?sub-page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub-page=$2 [L,QSA]

## three level virtual directory without /test/    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$1.php?sub-page=$2&sub-page2=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub-page=$2&sub-page2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: One thing I did not mention is that the primary page needs to be accessed, so I don't think this will work. I will update my original question. I also noticed the -f, I think this is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't work when going to /test/page-one. If I remove the RewriteCond it does, but then pages that do not exist do not get rewritten, IE. /test/test-one should write to index.php?test=1&page=test-one.

Comment: it would need to chack if page-one.php is in the DocumentRoor or pages, since the URL will call pages dynamically. I have added the current .htaccess, if you notice, I need to check if /test/ is called as the first directory, and it will basically do exactly what the current .htaccess does, but add ?test=1 to the vars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173158/discussion-between-anubhava-and-judson).